# Rails Admin bootstrap-sass and anjlab-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to use anjlab-bootstrap-rails gem. I'm also using Rails Admin.

When trying to log into the admin panel I get the following: couldn't find file 'bootstrap'

I added: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1' in my gem file.

How can I solve this problem. I want to use Bootstrap 3 with anjlab gem, but Rails Admin requires bootstrap-sass.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: Hey coletrain, I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: It seems if I just add an empty bootstrap.js file to my vender/javascript directory the error goes away.

Comment: @BrianRosedale I think you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the comments above I said just add bootstrap.js to your vendor/javascript directory, this is wrong.  This stops Rails Admin from complaining about the bootstrap.js file not being found, however, the bootstrap js files are not included.

The solution I came up with is the following:

1. Create bootstrap.js in your assets/javascript directory
2. Add the following to the bootstrap.js file:

   //= require twitter/bootstrap
3. Add the following to your config/application.rb

   config.assets.precompile += ['bootstrap.js']

This will add the require bootstrap files for your application, as well as Rails Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                              :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails',
                              :branch => '3.0.0'
```

in your gem file as it say [here](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails)

Answer (score 0):

The rails_admin guys gave a solution for this.

check here

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Troubleshoot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you please provide some context for your link? Also see the help [how do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Specialy the Provide context for links part.